# What Python library functions can one use to determine if a sample is drawn from a Laplace distribution?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, laplace-distribution

I have some data I suspect is drawn from a Laplace distribution rather than a Gaussian one.  I can use the Kolmogrov-Smirnov test and the ability to create Uniform and Gaussian distributions of the desired size to come up with a somewhat reliable test to disqualify that distribution as Guassian with p=0.001.  How can I do a similar exercise to disqualify the distribution as Laplace?

My guess is that values (for these samples) away from the mean decay at an exponential rate.  I would like to validate (or invalidate) that hypothesis.

My current code looks something like the following.

```
import scipy.stats as sct
    reference_dist = sct.uniform(loc = self.f_min, scale = self.f_max-self.f_min)
    ks_D_stat, p = sct.kstest(self.fa, reference_dist.cdf)
    if 0.001 < p:
        self.categorize(f"    {ks_D_stat = :.8} {p = :.8} uniform distribution\n")
    elif 20 <= self.fa.size:
        chi, p = sct.normaltest(self.fa)
        if 0.001 < p:
            self.categorize(f"    {chi = :.8} {p = :.8} Gaussian (Normal) distribution\n")
```

Comment: Hi @Chris. I don't know a specific Py package for this. I suspect survival style packages are typically well-used for distribution identification.

Comment: Thanks, that helps direct my search.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.